# Countries in dropdown : 2 digits to 3 digits

Tags: magento2, countries, source-model

I have a question about the source model "Country".

Currently, I can use, in my system.xml file, the following source_model :

`<source_model>Magento\Directory\Model\Config\Source\Country</source_model>`

In my Stores > Configuration, I can see my dropdown with the list of all countries.

But when I see the code, I can see my select option have only two digits as value, example :

`<option value="AF">Afghanistan</option>`

But I would like 3 digits, example :

`<option value="AFG">Afghanistan</option>`

Do you know how can I change that ? Did I need change the source model, or may be it's an option somewhere ?

Thanks !

Comment: I do not recommend CHANGING hte source model. but rather provide your own

Comment: I need 3 digits, I can't change that. So did you know any way ?

Comment: provide your onw source model

Comment: So 3 digits countries not exist in Magento 2 ? Here I can see the link between 2 and 3 digits so I thought that was possible to switch.. : http://www.nextbits.eu/blog/magento-country-codes-for-shipping-methods-table-rate/

Comment: they do exist.... but there is not simple "switch"

Comment: I don't want to create my own source_model if one already exist with country 3 digits.. Wen you say it's not a simple switch, what do you mean ?